# How to test an instance method that calls an async function defined outside my project?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I need to test a method of a custom view controller. The method looks something like this:

```swift
func generateToken() {
        // Some validations

        let delegate = TokenizationDelegate() // This class is defined in an external dependency
        delegate.tokenizeCard(model: cardModel) { response in
            // Business logic
        } failBlock: { error in
            // Show error view
        }
    }
```

What would be the best way to test this? I was trying to use a XCTestExpectation, but the `generateToken()` method doesn't take any parameters so I can pass a closure where I can fulfill the expectation...

I'm trying to achieve a 100% coverage on this method, and right now I see in the coverage report that the closures aren't covered.

Preferably I would not want to modify the signature of the method `generateToken()`, but if there's no other way to test it, I'm open to hear suggestions!

Comment: it seems that in your current design, `generateToken` is untestable since it operates asynchronously but doesn't communicate its completion state to callers.  This indicates that you probably need to refactor this function. Your comment says "show error view".  This probably shouldn't be the responsibility of this function.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The reason you can't test this is that you didn't make it testable. "Preferably I would not want to modify the signature of the method generateToken()" is silly; why would you not want to? Refactoring goes on all the time. You gotta do what you gotta do. You _certainly_ must test this.

Comment: And yes, the way to test something asynchronous is to use asynchronous testing. But let's cross that bridge when we come to it. Right now you need to start mocking TokenizationDelegate. The fact that it isn't yours is irrelevant.

Comment: Alright, I get your points. But I didn't quite understood why calling a method that shows an error view on the view controller isn't its responsability.
Also, I didn't want to modify its signature because I didn't write this code, and I'm adding this tests to reach coverage in the PR, refactoring it would scape the scope of the PR

Comment: You have not shown anywhere near enough code for me to answer intelligently. You say "shows an error view" but no code you've shown causes anything to show anything. You don't need to test here that anything is shown, but you do need to test that the _command_ to do that showing is given.

Comment: As Matt says, there is not enough code, but my impression is that you have two separate operations here; One is to fetch a token.  The second is to display an error view.  If you want to be able to test properly then you need to separate those operations. Alternatively you could decide not to test `TokenizationDelegate` since that is an external service that (presumably) has its own tests.  So your test case could be "Function displays an error view if tokenisation fails".  You would need to be able to inject a mock token service that fails and use UI testing to test the result

Comment: In order to be able to test this function it needs to either always update the UI state, in which case you can test it using UI testing, or provide some exposed success/fail in which case you can use functional testing. The implication from the comments is that on success it affects application state but not (necessarily) the UI and on failure it shows an error (affects the UI) but does not update application state.  Your success and fail cases are incompatible.  If you refactor to separate the error display from the app state update it becomes more testable

Comment: Thank you both for your reply. Finally, I mocked TokenizationDelegate as you suggested, to force success or failure and go on both paths and I pass it to the function as a parameter. If you post the answer I'll accept it right away